# How is this Edit text field static content?

Tags: android, android-fragments

When I try to implement this below piece of code, it gives the below error. What I dont understand is how's the `EditText` input field a static content? It might be something very basic that I might be missing here.

```
 Error:(28, 32) error: non-static method findViewById(int) cannot be referenced from a static context
```

Code:

```
package com.example.kheriaa.meme_fragments_v1;

    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.EditText;


    public class TopSectionFragment extends Fragment {

        private  EditText TopText;
        private  EditText BottomText ;


        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frags_layout, container, false);

          TopText = (EditText) View.findViewById(R.id.TopText);

            //return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            return v;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
TopText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.TopText);
```

instead of

```
TopText = (EditText) View.findViewById(R.id.TopText);
```

The `Fragment` class does not have a `findViewById`() method; the `Activity` does, though. The compiler is complaining because this Fragment is a static inner class of an Activity, so it thinks you're trying to call that method.

If you are trying to get a view from the Fragment layout, then change `findViewById()` to `rootView.findViewById().`

If you're trying to get a view from the `Activity` layout, then change it to `getActivity().findViewById()`

Comment: Is this because my view object is "V"? and not view?

Comment: @supersayan Yes because the instance of View is v , so u should use     v.findViewById(R.id.TopText);

Comment: @supersayan i added the explanation

Answer (score 0):

You should override the methond onActivityCreated and then use

TopText = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.TopText);

BTW rafsanahmad007 is completle right with his answer just make sure you do it from in the onActivityCreated because the fragment and the activity life cycle are indivudals so onCreateView might be called BEFORE onActivityCreated.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this `TopText = (EditText) View.findViewById(R.id.TopText);`with `TopText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.TopText);`